# What does "make it last" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-meaning

There is a song but I am not sure about the meaning of "make it last" in that song. Please let me know what it means and which situation I should use this?

**Make it last - Tim Mc Morris**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_cCVzyH8cY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam Webster Last intransitive/transitive verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/last)

> Meaning *to continue for a long time*.

So make it last means make it continue for a long time (long being subjective as bridges are built to last for a hundred years or more while clothes are made to last for maybe ten years)

In the song he wants the feeling of being with his girlfriend to last, to continue to have that feeling for a long time.

You can use it in many situations

- Don't drink all the milk, we have to make it last.
- Can you fix this and make it last ?
- We tried but it didn't last (where something you hoped would go on for a long time doesn't)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So this means here is to make his love last (longer than ever)?

Comment: @PMay1903 That's it. He is enjoying the feeling he gets with his girlfriend and he doesn't want it to end.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to stay here with you Under sunny skies, lookin in your big
>   brown eyes Time goes by but my heart stays true And every smile you
>   give, your love it shine right through And in this moment
>
> I’ll make it last, make it last, I’ll take my time, and make it last
>   And as the present becomes the past, I’ll do my best to make it last
>   I’ll make it last, make it last, whatever it takes I’ll make it last
>   And though the future is coming fast, I’ll fight it off to make this
>   last Everybody seems to think that all good things come to an end But
>   I won’t fall for that, oh no, forever you will be my friend And no one
>   else can make feel the way you without effort do And you are mine, for
>   now and always, and always know that I love you
>
> And so I’ll make it last, make it last, I’ll take my time, and make it
>   last And as the present becomes the past, I’ll do my best to make it
>   last I’ll make it last, make it last, whatever it takes I’ll make it
>   last And though the future is coming fast, I’ll fight it off to make
>   this last

The song is about the future, more so that the present.

He is speaking of the feeling that you have when your are new lovers, and how time diminishes it.  His "I'll make it last" refrain is a [nuncupation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nuncupate), more so than anything else.

> I’ll make it last, make it last, I’ll take my time, and make it last
>   And as the present becomes the past, I’ll do my best to make it last
>   I’ll make it last, make it last, whatever it takes I’ll make it
>   last...I’ll make it last, make it last, whatever it takes I’ll make it
>   last And though the future is coming fast, I’ll fight it off to make
>   this last